# Extract String from another string in Java

Tags: java, string, extract

Here is a string:

```
"http://l2.yimg.com/bt/api/res/1.2/iis49xBsStLiYI6LjauR6Q--/YXBwaWQ9eW5ld3M7Zmk9ZmlsbDtoPTg2O3E9NzU7dz0xMzA-/http://media.zenfs.com/fr_FR/News/LeMonde.fr/1515504_3_f73c_le-cyber-harcelement-est-une-realite-trop-lo_450282425a88c544c2ff4121a5d9dab4.jpg"
```

This string is a concatenation of two URLs. I would like to extract only the second URL:

```
"http://media.zenfs.com/fr_FR/News/LeMonde.fr/1515504_3_f73c_le-cyber-harcelement-est-une-realite-trop-lo_450282425a88c544c2ff4121a5d9dab4.jpg"
```

How can I do that using Java?

Comment: A simple `str.substring(str.indexOf("http://", 1))` is enough.

Comment: I like `str.substring(108)`.  It does exactly what the poster asked for.

Answer (score 2):

Remove everything up to "http://" not found at the start:

```
String url2 = str.replaceAll("(?i).+(?=https?://)", "");
```

This will work case insensitively and match `http` or `https` protocols.

Comment: +1 for handling `https`, although I hardly believe case insensitivity is necessary.

Comment: thanks, but I'm working [pro bono](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pro_bono) atm - capped out hours ago :)

Comment: +1; I didn't know that you can use `(?<flags>)` in java.

Comment: @RyanCarlson afaik `(?ims)` are supported. global is on by default.

Comment: It doesn't say anywhere on [`Pattern`'s summary](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#sum), but I did find another interesting thing: in the regex `(abc((?i)xyz)`, `xyz` is case insensitive, but `abc` isn't.

Comment: same can be said for `abc(?i)xyz` - flags turn switches on for the *remainder* of the regex

Answer (score 2):

Try this. "str" is the url string

```
System.out.println(str.substring(str.lastIndexOf("http:")));
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to extract the URL, just find the last instance of `http`, and take the substring:

```
String secondUrl = firstUrl.substring(firstUrl.lastIndexOf("http"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using string's [`.split()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) method, like this:

```
String oneURL = twoURLs.split("(?<!^)(?=http://)")[1];
```

This splits the string in places that are not at the end of the string, but are followed by `http://`. With that, you should end up with an array like this:

```
["http://l2.yimg.com/bt/api/res/1.2/iis49xBsStLiYI6LjauR6Q--/YXBwaWQ9eW5ld3M7Zmk9ZmlsbDtoPTg2O3E9NzU7dz0xMzA-/", "http://media.zenfs.com/fr_FR/News/LeMonde.fr/1515504_3_f73c_le-cyber-harcelement-est-une-realite-trop-lo_450282425a88c544c2ff4121a5d9dab4.jpg"]
```

`[1]` takes only the second element of that array.

Explanation and demonstration of the regex here: http://regex101.com/r/eW6mZ0